# Can't output from .hs to .hc with GHC in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, ghc, haskell-platform

I was intrigued when I heard that GHC can output a file to C .

> The Glasgow Haskell Compiler (GHC) compiles to native code on a number of different architectures—as well as to ANSI C—using C-- as an intermediate language.

So I installed the Haskell Platform and created a simple .hs file.

```
main = putStrLn "Hello, World!"
```

And according to the manual.

> -C Stop after generating C (.hc file)

Now I run the command.

```
ghc -C test.hs
```

But it doesn't create a .hc file, nor does it stop mid-compilation.

```
$ ls
test.exe  test.hi  test.hs  test.o
```

Comment: Have you tried passing -fvia-C in addition to -C? IIRC GHC doesn't use the C backend by default (it can directly generate assemblies for various machine, including llvm).

Comment: I got a warning saying that "The -fvia-C flag does nothing; it will be removed in a future GHC release". Augustss, why would I be disappointed?

Comment: It looks entirely unlike C code a human would write.  It's basically unreadable.  It's also not as efficient as you'd hope.  The only way it gets efficient is by mangling the assembly code generated by the C compiler.

Comment: Afaik, GHC has booted the C backend completely, including scrapping C generation from the compiler. If you want to, you can look at the C-- (`--ddump-cmm`) or the assembly (`-ddump-asm`) but I'm afraid that's as close as you get. GHC generates really weird code, but you can learn to make sense of "GHC-style" imperative code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to understand how Haskell programs execute at a low level, it is probably best to study Core instead (`-ddump-simpl`). After that point the code becomes really hard to read even for experts. The main reason is that GHC's stack and heap management gets hard-coded. As a result, low-level generated Haskell code is basically a giant mess of tiny procedures, doing complex pointer arithmetic before finishing with indirect jumps to unknown locations. The worst kind of spaghetti code.

To provide something of an actual answer - you *could* generate C by going over the LLVM backend:

```
ghc -ddump-llvm -ddump-to-file hello_world.hs
opt -O2 hello_world.dump-llvm | llc -O2 -march c -o hello_world.c
```

But the result will just illustrate the point. Even a trivial `fib` function will take about 80 lines of code.

In case you are really interested in the gory details, I would recommend reading through [this blog post](http://blog.ezyang.com/2011/04/tracing-the-compilation-of-hello-factorial/) by Edward Z. Yang. He basically walks through the whole compilation pipeline involved in translating a simple piece of Haskell code.

Comment: Awesome, got it in C++.

Transforms to this apparently :D http://pastebin.com/r4Dy0ZD5

Comment: Note that the C++ code you pasted is actually a *generator* for the final machine code (using LLVM as a library). But trying to run it is futile in any case, trust me...

Comment: is this still expected to work with ghc 7.10? `opt` gives an error on my `.dump-llvm` file "expected top-level entity"

Comment: This is probably about the extra "==..." markers and dates that the dump adds. You will have to remove them to make it valid LLVM code. Alternatively, do `ghc ... -fllvm -keep-tmp-files -v` and use the file name ending in `.ll` file from the verbose output.